# How to add a module on my page in DNN programatically

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

So far, I have tried below code to add a module through code on my page in DNN.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ModuleController MC = new ModuleController();
       ModuleInfo MInfo = new ModuleInfo();
       MInfo = MC.GetModule(507, 116,false);//Just Hard coded for testing 
       MInfo.TabID = PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID;
       MInfo.PaneName = "ContentPane";
       MInfo.Alignment = "left";
       MC.AddModule(MInfo);//Line throwing error :-

}
```

I am trying to add a module which is present on `tabid=116` and having `moduleId=507` on my current tab or page in `pageLoad` Event.But the last line throwing a error saying

```
"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_TabModules_UniqueId'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TabModules'. The duplicate key value is (555ba77a-be19-40a0-bb72-559672230345)."
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong ? and  is this the correct way to add a module ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing that I notice is that you're effectively trying to add the same instance of the module to the database.  You've changed the `TabID`, but otherwise all of the other IDs within the `ModuleInfo` instance are still there.

Looking at [how DNN adds an existing module](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/6d382d62f0719a614c10370efa6dd70be879a644/Website/admin/ControlPanel/AddModule.ascx.cs#L433-L542) (look in the `DoAddExistingModule` method), they start by calling `Clone()` on the `ModuleInfo` instance, and then reset the `UniqueId` (which is the constraint you're hitting):

```
newModule.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: That's what was hanging me up too.  Thanks Brian!